# Using Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the remainder when divided by 990.

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm still revising for my final (this class is absolutely killing me) and I need some help on the following problem:

*What is the remainder when the number $101102103104105...996997998$ is divided by $990$?*

The question says that CRT must be used. I actually found an alternative answer to this question on this site (link: [Remainder when dividing by 990: Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283035/remainder-when-dividing-by-990-chinese-remainder-theorem)) and understand the policy on duplicates, but I wish to know how we can use CRT on such a large number.

If we were to set $x = 101102103104105...996997998$, then based on the factors of $990$, we would get $x = k\pmod{10}$, $x = k\pmod{11}$ and $x = k \pmod9$. But how can I apply the CRT on such a large number?

Thanks! And sorry about the very similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $x$ is indeed large but we can simplify its computation $\!\bmod 9\ \&\ 11\,$ using $\,10^{\large 3}\equiv \pm1\,$  and this makes the arithmetic so simple that it can all be done purely mentally, i.e.

$\!\!\bmod 11\!:\ 10^{\large 3}\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv (998\!-\!997) + (996\!-\!995)+\cdots + (102\!-\!101)\equiv \overbrace{449\cdot 1\equiv  9}^{\large \equiv\ 4\ -\ 4\ +\ 9}$

$\!\!\bmod 9\!:\ \ \ 10^{\large 3}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow x\equiv \begin{align} &\ \ \ \ \ 998+997+\cdots+\color{#0a0}{550}\\
                                  &+101+102+\cdots+\color{#0a0}{549}\end{align}\equiv 449(\color{#0a0}{1099})\equiv (4\!+\!4\!+\!9)(1\!+\!9\!+\!9)\equiv 8$

$\!\!\bmod 10\!:\ \ x\equiv 8\,$ too, thus  by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) $\ x\equiv 8\pmod{\!90}.\ $ By above $\,x\equiv 9\pmod{\!11},\,$ so by CRT

$\!\!\bmod\color{#c00}{ 11}\!:\,\ 9\equiv x\equiv 8+90\,\color{#c00}k\equiv 8+2k\iff 2k\equiv 1\equiv 12\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 6}$

so we deduce:$\ \ x = 8 + 90(\color{#c00}{6\!+\!11}n) = 548+ 990n$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for $9,10,11$?  Apply each of them to get the remainder modulo those.  For example, as the number ends in $8$ it is equivalent to $8 \bmod 10$.  What is the sum of all the digits?  That gives the remainder $\bmod 9$.  Then find a number less than $990$ that has the right three remainders.